# Sort UITableView in Russian alphabetical order

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios

I'm a noob, and I'm sorry because the question is really stupid. I have An NSArray which contains titles for UITableView rows in NSDictionaries in Russian and I need to sort these titles in alphabetical order. How can I do it?

Help me, please.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS 4.0 and later, you can use a sort descriptor. Assuming `title` is the key under which your title strings are stored in the dictionaries:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                         [NSArray arrayWithObject:
                          [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title"
                                                        ascending:YES
                                                         selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]]];
```

Another option is to use a block-based sort method:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSString *string1 = [(NSDictionary *)obj1 objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *string2 = [(NSDictionary *)obj2 objectForKey:@"title"];
    return [string1 localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:string2];
}];
```

If you need your app to run on iOS 3.1.3 and earlier, however, you can either:

- write a comparison method as a category on NSDictionary and pass it to `-sortedArrayUsingSelector:`, or
- write a comparison function and pass it to `-sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:`.

In each case, your method or function's body will be essentially the same as the body of the block in the second example above. The [NSArray class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) contains examples of both techniques.

Comment: Thank you! It worked for titles which names are two different words. But if there are two words and the first one is the same for both, the app crashes :(

Comment: Really? Odd... Where is the crash happening, in your code or in localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare?

Comment: No, it happens in my code, although without the sorting everything works Fine. It crashes at  *NSDictionary * dictionary = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];*    and the console shows      *Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6999e80'*

Comment: UPD: Figured it out, it was my fault in my code. Thank you sooooo much! You're a lifesaver!

Comment: Looks like you're somehow assigning an NSString to sortedArray instead of the return value of -sortedArrayUsingXXX. Not sure how you'd do that accidentally, since it requires a cast. Are you certain that's the line that's throwing the exception?

Comment: Oops, didn't see your last comment. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will sort your array:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f7f260'

Comment: Are you sure that your NSArray contains NSStrings? You might want to iterate over it, logging each string - just to check. I have seen similar problems before and if I recall correctly I was over-releasing elements of an array and then trying to access them.

Comment: No, it doesn't contain NSStrings, it contains NSDictionaries with NSStrings it them. Sorry, maybe I was unclear